# How to test the Geo location in mobile, please explain with real time scenario

Tags: manual-testing

How to test the Geo location in mobile, please explain with real time scenario and in during testing which location setting is good device location or high accuracy setting?

Comment: Use emulators. They allow to set up the location your app would detect in a real device

Answer (score 1):

> How to test the Geo location in mobile

Your first question I believe was answered in [How to test dynamic GPS location in mobile](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/how-to-test-dynamic-gps-location-in-mobile?rq=1)
But of course, real case scenario, when walking outside and inside with your phone(s) shall be carried out at least from time to time.

> which location setting is good device location or high accuracy setting?

If you really want to test real case scenario, you should test both.
**Device only mode** relies solely on the GPS radio signal built into your phone. It works using the GPS-designated network of satellites to find your phone's location. This means it will work in places where you won't find enough Wi-Fi, cellular towers, and Bluetooth beacons to get a proper location.

When you select the **High accuracy** location service mode, you are allowing multiple networks to pinpoint your precise location (hence the name High accuracy). It calls for every service available: GPS, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and/or cellular networks in whatever combination available to provide the most accurate location.

Because the device only mode is less accurate, especially in buildings, you should check that also how much reliable is your application-under-test in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the Geo location by either taking the device for a walk within and outside perimeter or by spoofing the location in your device. Compared to device location, high accuracy setting would be more accurate.